# Is there a word/expression that would correspond to something like "self-distance"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In Swedish there is a term called *självdistans*, which would be directly translated to "self-distance", which means possessing a certain objectivity towards yourself, to be ego-less or not taking yourself too seriously. In other words, it's a quality in a person that would be modest and not too egoistic. Important thing to stress here is that an apparent lack of "self-distance" is a negative thing while too much self-distance can also be seen as a negative trait as it would been that you are actively trying to avoid giving yourself credit for something you have done, or dismiss any praise you might get from others.

I am not sure if what I am trying to get at is clear enough or if I should try to explain it better. At any rate, I am trying to find a word or expression to express the same quality but I can't seem to find "self-distance" in any English dictionary. Is there a good, semi-formal word that fits in this context?

Comment: I suggest the word "meekness."  Meekness is not weakness, but strength under control.  Meek people have an inner strength enabling them to pick the battles worth fighting.  Insults directed at them they merely shrug off.  Insults directed at the helpless and the weak they counter with righteous indignation.  Hubristic people try to gain the whole world but lose their souls in the process.  Meek people, on the other hand, "will inherit the earth."   We can exalt ourselves now and be humbled later, or we can humble ourselves now and be exalted later.  The choice is ours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider words such as **modesty** and **humility**.  These are both seen as being positive traits but could be taken to an extreme where a person doesn't take appropriate credit for their accomplishments or abilities.

Another word to consider would be **objectivity**.  This captures the sense of lack of egotism, but it isn't necessarily understood to be reflexive.

Comment: "Reserved" seems to fit in as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Self-aware** is commonly used to describe a healthy objectivity toward oneself, though the formal definition is more limited.

**Self-effacing** captures the idea of modesty, potentially to a fault.

I don't know of an English word that combines both concepts in the way your Swedish term does.

Answer (score 1):

**self-possession**

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-possession?show=0&t=1364577607): control of one's emotions or reactions especially when under stress : presence of mind, composure
>
> [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-possession): the state or feeling of being calm, confident, and in control of one’s feelings; composure: *an air of self-possession*
>
> [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-possession): Full command of one's faculties, feelings, and behavior. See Synonyms at [confidence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confidence): ... *Self-possession* implies composure arising from control over one's own reactions: *"In life courtesy and self-possession . . . are the sensible impressions of the free mind, for both arise . . . from never being swept away, whatever the emotion, into confusion or dullness"* (William Butler Yeats).

Although less literal a match than the other answers, I think you may want to consider this term for the purpose you intended, or the person you intended.  It seems *självdistans* emphasizes inner perspective while self-possession is about inner behavior, but they may converge on the same character trait:  not being ruled by one's own emotions.  After all, which emotion is more remarkable to be free of than self love?  I wonder if this distinction may reflect culture, Swedish emphasizing self-image, English self-control.  Almost thought versus action.

Whomever deserves this description in your book, I like them already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that although there's a Swedish word that can be used in certain contexts, I suspect it's quite likely different Swedes would interpret even that word differently.

For example, a person might be said to have the *självdistans* attribute if he ***acts*** in an *objective* manner (because he's deliberately being *equitable, evenhanded, impartial, impersonal*). These meanings all tend towards a general concept of *fairness*.

But another Swede may say a person has the *självdistans* attribute if they lack a strong sense of *personal identity*. Clinically speaking, people with [autism/Asperger's syndrome](http://www.lookingupautism.org/Articles/Asperger-brain-signal.html) fall into that category (the link says they *'lack brain signal linked to sense of self'*). That's an extreme case, but there are a whole host of words in that general area (*egoless, detached, unengaged*, etc.).

There are also plenty of words involving *spirituality, serenity, unworldliness*, etc.

And if a person lacks the ability to protect their own interests, they're *naive, gullible, artless*, etc.

All such words will come with connotations, but probably OP's own **objectivity** would be the best word for most contexts, if he wants to minimise positive/negative associations.

Comment: interesting points..

Answer (score 1):

**Balanced ego** might fit your need. As the phrase suggests, a person with a balanced ego has one that is optimum, neither too strong (bad) nor too weak (also bad), but in the middle (good).

A similar phrase is **balanced personality**.

Answer (score 0):

Self-effacing is the closest thing I've found. **Self-effacement** is the act or fact of keeping oneself in the background, as in humility. You could also use the word **withdrawn**

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Self-effacing was suggested by Tom. Please expand your answer and explain how "withdrawn" could be used with proper reference. You need to note that if you leave such a short answer, it could be automatically flagged by the system.

Comment: "Withdrawn" has a mostly negative connotation, which is not what the question is asking for. This just leaves your suggestion of "self-effacing". To distinguish your answer from Tom's, I recommend you look up the expression in an online dictionary and use the "edit" button to paste the definition. You can paste the link by using the "chain link" symbol in the formatting bar. If you did the same for "humility", and deleted the reference to "withdrawn", I would definitely vote for your answer as a useful addition.